# Replace special characters in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, replace, urllib

I am using urllib to get a string of html from a website and need to put each word in the html document into a list.

Here is the code I have so far. I keep getting an error. I have also copied the error below.

```
import urllib.request

url = input("Please enter a URL: ")

z=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
z=str(z.read())
removeSpecialChars = str.replace("!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+", " ")

words = removeSpecialChars.split()

print ("Words list: ", words[0:20])
```

Here is the error.

```
Please enter a URL: http://simleyfootball.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeremy.KLUG\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Python Project 2\Module2.py", line 7, in <module>
    removeSpecialChars = str.replace("!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+", " ")
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

str.replace is the wrong function for what you want to do (apart from it being used incorrectly). You want to replace any character of a set with a space, not the whole set with a single space (the latter is what replace does). You can use translate like this:

```
removeSpecialChars = z.translate ({ord(c): " " for c in "!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+"})
```

This creates a mapping which maps every character in your list of special characters to a space, then calls translate() on the string, replacing every single character in the set of special characters with a space.

Comment: Are you sure regex will perform better than translate? translate might be using regex internally ?

Comment: Very well done for the `ord` use! Otherwise str.translate on special characters does nothing.

Comment: Thanks! This answer saved my day.

Comment: Note that this replaces anything IN a set of characters, while [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23996414/2025495) replaces anything NOT IN a regex match. The latter is probably a safer approach if the goal is to make a string "safe" for a given context.

Answer (score 128):

One way is to use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.sub), that's my preferred way.

```
import re
my_str = "hey th~!ere"
my_new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', my_str)
print my_new_string
```

**Output:**

```
hey there
```

Another way is to use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
import string
import re

my_str = "hey th~!ere"

chars = re.escape(string.punctuation)
print re.sub('['+chars+']', '',my_str)
```

**Output:**

```
hey there
```

**Just a small tip** about parameters style in python by [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) parameters should be `remove_special_chars` and not `removeSpecialChars`

Also if you want to **keep** the spaces just change `[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]` to `[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]`

Comment: +1 clearly the fastest and best answer
it handles every case, translate will not do anything if given strange utf8 characters,
re.sub with negative regex  [^...] is much safer.

Comment: how to replace the character ` using re.sub?

Comment: very helpfull answer, but on the last line don't you mean that using  [^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.] will REMOVE the spaces ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to call `replace` on `z` and not on `str`, since you want to replace characters located in the string variable `z`

```
removeSpecialChars = z.replace("!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+", " ")
```

But this will not work, as replace looks for a substring, you will most likely need to use regular expression module `re` with the `sub` function:

```
import re
removeSpecialChars = re.sub("[!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+]", " ", z)
```

Don't forget the `[]`, which indicates that this is a set of characters to be replaced.

Comment: This is wrong. The [] within the square brackets needs to be espaced and the -  needs to be at the end as otherwise it will be a range. Do re.sub("[!@#$%^&*(){};:,./<>?\|`~=_\[\]-]", " ", z) instead.

Answer (score 0):

replace operates on a specific string, so you need to call it like this

```
removeSpecialChars = z.replace("!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+", " ")
```

but this is probably not what you need, since this will look for a single string containing all that characters in the same order. you can do it with a regexp, as Danny Michaud pointed out.

as a side note, you might want to look for [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which is a library for parsing messy HTML formatted text like what you usually get from scaping websites.

Comment: I have to use just the libraries included in python. Is there regex that could accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: it depends on whether you are about to work with English texts, texts that include foreign words (with accents, umlauts, etc.), digits, currency symbols etc. There is no universal regex to "clean up stuff", you need to be specific about what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the special characters with the desired characters as follows,

```
import string
specialCharacterText = "H#y #@w @re &*)?"
inCharSet = "!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+\""
outCharSet = "                               " #corresponding characters in inCharSet to be replaced
splCharReplaceList = string.maketrans(inCharSet, outCharSet)
splCharFreeString = specialCharacterText.translate(splCharReplaceList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate seems faster:

N=100000, 30 special characters, string length=70

replace:   0.3251810073852539
re.sub:    0.2859320640563965
translate: 0.12320685386657715