# DataFrame to CSV creates empty files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have one large dataframe  which I am splitting into multiple smaller dataframes based on a particular column and want to save each of these smaller dataframes as individual csv files.

`all_parameters` is a list of strings that appear in a particular column of the dataframe. `column_name` is the column in dataframe `df`that has the names I am interested in.

```
for parameter in all_parameters:
    output_filename=str(parameter)+'_char.txt'
    df_param=df.loc[df[column_name]==parameter]
    df_param.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
    print("\n"+output_filename)
    print(df_param.head())
    df_param.to_csv(output_filename)
```

Each dataframe `df_param` prints as expected but when I try to save to a csv, it just creates 0KB files with a name without the `'_char.txt'`

If I change to a fixed filename as in `df_param.to_csv('1.txt')` it saves the last file in the loop correctly.

To clarify- The print statement in the code above generates multiple dataframes like this:

```
[5 rows x 11 columns]

s8srssf8a_VTRIP_LVPORBOD_fall:tripLevel_char.txt
   x  y  SITE     ...           Data             Source Table  Temperature
0  6  1     1     ...       1610.436    1D.001.20190131091926           25
1  6  1     1     ...       1548.332  1D.001.20190131103844U1          130
2  5  1     1     ...       1608.646    1D.001.20190131120359          -40
3  8  1     1     ...       1597.414    1D.001.20190131120359          -40
4  1  1     1     ...       1608.345    1D.001.20190131111528           90

[5 rows x 11 columns]

s8srssf8a_VTRIP_LVPORBOD_rise:tripLevel_char.txt
   x  y  SITE     ...           Data             Source Table  Temperature
0  3  1     1     ...       1574.713  1D.001.20190131103844U1          130
1  1  1     1     ...       1529.827  1D.001.20190131103844U1          130
2  2  1     1     ...       1621.061    1D.001.20190131091926           25
3  1  1     1     ...       1631.120    1D.001.20190131091926           25
4  7  1     1     ...       1625.103    1D.001.20190131120359          -40
```

What is going on here? Help please!

Comment: Ok, I just answered my own question.  Turns out that special characters are not allowed for file names in windows, so it just truncated the name upto the point of the special character and created an empty file. Used this to remove special characters in the filename  and works now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996118/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-python

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the `:` in the file name. Why dont you try knocking that off from the filename.