# replace \n from a list in a data frame

Tags: regex, pandas

I have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'text':[['\nThere are a lot of\n things that \nare worthy','\nS\nU\nP\nE\nR'],['\nAnd there is \nlots to see']]})
df
0   [\nThere are a lot of\n things that \nare wort...
1   [\nAnd there is \nlots to see]
```

I want to replace all \n's, and keep the same structure.

I tried:

```
df['new']=df.text.str.replace('\n','')
    text    new
0   [\nThere are a lot of\n things that \nare wort...   NaN
1   [\nAnd there is \nlots to see]  NaN
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Why the double-nested list? It works if I try it with a flat list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
import re
df['new'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: [re.sub(r'\n', '', y) for y in x])
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you can try is to use another escape character to be sure that is fetched as string.

```
df['new']=df.text.str.replace('\\n','')
```

Second case, i would suggest to use the method explained in this answer with the "re" library

[replace special characters in a string python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996118/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-python)