# Python reading from an xml file without the special characters

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree2 = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\W\Desktop\220-01.xml')
root = tree2.getroot()
txt = ""
for c in root:
    txt += c.text
    break;
```

I wrote this above code a month ago so apologies for importing both libraries, I think I only use one. I only need to read from the first root, but the issue is the way the text is stored has special characters, for example:
"\n\n\nPatient went"
Is there a way to get rid of the \n's? I have similar issue with other special characters too, I want the text to look exactly like it does within the xml document because the indices are very important for my work.
Thanks

EDIT: I found a working solution for the time being, after some more searching I ran into this post: [replace special characters in a string python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996118/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-python)
And with the suggestion from user 'Kobi K' what I did was replace all the \n's with " " 's, this somehow maintained the integrity of the document and the indices still match how I want.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: provide the input file please.