# Replacing items in python without using if

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I want to replace special characters that come between alphanumeric characters in a string without using if conditions. An efficient way to do it??

Comment: Can you provide an example string and the code of your tries? Check [replace special characters in a string python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996118/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace method for string. But if you need to replace a specific group of characters there regex will come to help. [Python Regex Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.)

A simpler version of documentation is here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp