# Python: replacing unusual characters in a text file

Tags: replace, unicode

I am trying to do the following changes/substitutions automatically, in a text file.

```
â€\u9d  = "
â€œ = "
â€™ = '
â€” = :
```

I consistently run into the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 452: character maps to <undefined>

Here's my recent code:

```
fin = open("example.md", "rt")
data = fin.read()
data = data.replace(r'â€\u9d', '\"')
data = data.replace(r'â€œ', '\"')
data = data.replace(r'â€™', '\"')
data = data.replace(r'â€”', ':')


fin.close()
fin = open("data.txt", "wt")
fin.write(data)
fin.close()
```

Comment: Looks like a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Try `open("example.md", "rt", encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: Python's open defaults to the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` which is usually `cp1252`. `cp1252` doesn't support decoding `\x9d`. Be explicit and use `encoding='utf8'` as suggested. The garbage will come out as smart quotes and em dashes instead.  Note `\u9d` is not a valid escape code, but your error is on the `.read()` line.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996118/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-python) ,u can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.sub), such below :

```
import re
my_str = "hey th~!ere"
my_new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', my_str)
print my_new_string
```

I test it, is working :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First is that you're opening the file with the wrong encoding, leading to a case of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) as suggested by @JosefZ in the comments.  The solution is exactly as he suggested:

```
fin = open("example.md", "rt", encoding="utf-8")
```

The second problem is that you're using a very ham-fisted way of correcting the first problem.  You may find that once you read the characters correctly there's no need to fix them.  But if you still need to convert curly quotes to straight ones so that everything's compatible with ASCII, there's a much easier way to do that with the [`unidecode` module](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/).

```
from unidecode import unidecode
data = unidecode(data)
```

This will take care of all the characters listed in your question, and more besides.