# How to effectively replace special chars and spaces with single underscore?

Tags: python, regex, replace

How can I easily replace special characters and space with an underscore `_`, but also multiple underscores with a single `_`?

My approach below, but it's not pretty.

```
import string

s = 'Hi th@re gu^ys!@#()tes   t;"[]ing'

for chr in string.punctuation + string.whitespace:
    s = s.replace(chr, '_')

while '__' in s:
    s = s.replace('__', '_')

print(s)  # Hi_th_re_gu_ys_tes_t_ing
```

versien 2:

```py
dont_want_these = frozenset(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)

def repl_it(s):
    chrs = list(s)
    prev_chr_was_fail = False

    for i, chr in enumerate(chrs):
        if chr in dont_want_these:
            if prev_chr_was_fail:
                chrs[i] = ''
            else:
                prev_chr_was_fail = True
                chrs[i] = '_'
        else:
            prev_chr_was_fail = False

    return ''.join(chrs)

assert repl_it('Hi th@re gu^ys!@#()tes   t;"[]ing') == 'Hi_th_re_gu_ys_tes_t_ing'
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace special characters in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996118/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: nope, i tried a couple answers in the linked question but it didnt give me the desired output

Comment: Please define "special character".

Comment: actually I found a better solution which solves my use case, where I wanted to strip unnecessary chars and also check for diff casing like camel and pascal etc. I decide to use [pyheck](https://github.com/kevinheavey/pyheck) which is a pretty fast inflection library, which I think also does exactly what I'm looking for too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import re

new_s1 = re.sub(r'[\W_]+','_',s1)
new_s2 = re.sub(r'[\W_]+','_',s2)
```

Input:

```py
s1 = 'Hi th@re gu^ys!@#()tes   t;"[]ing'
s2 = 'Hi th@re gu^ys!@#()tes   t___;"[]ing'
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(new_s1)
>>> Hi_th_re_gu_ys_tes_t_ing
>>> print(new_s2)
>>> Hi_th_re_gu_ys_tes_t_ing
```

Comment: awesome thanks, that works. also looks like it's the fastest version even between the two non-regex ones I had come up with.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'Hi th@re gu^ys!@#()tes   t;"[]ing'
new_s = re.sub(r'[\W]+','_',s)
print(new_s)
```

Comment: `also multiple underscores with a single _`. This doesn't seem to do this since `_` is considered a word character.

Comment: thanks guys. also @Mark I did note that `r'[\W_]+'` works when input has consecutive `_` as mentioned, so will give it a pass as working for most part.