# How to replace special characters in string - selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a piece of code as follows. I want to take a header and remove the special symbols " !@#$%^&* " from it, but I've tried everything but still can't. Hope everyone can help, thank you very much

```
        try:
        title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/article/div[3]/p[1]/span').text
        print(title)

        if title.count("#") > 0:
            titles.append(title)
            titles[number] = title[0:title.index('#')]
            number += 1
        else:
            titles.append(title)
            number += 1

        if titles[number-1] == '':
            titles[number-1] = f"Invalid Title"
            
        banned_char = '<>:"/\|?*'
        for character in banned_char:
            if title.count(character) > 0:
                titles[number-1] = title[title.replace('<>:"/\|?*',' ')]
    except:
        titles.append(f'Failed Title number {number}')
        number+=1
        print(f'Download {number} have no title.')
```

Comment: Does this answers to your query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996118/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: how about `.replace('<',' ').replace('>',' ').replace(':',' ')` ? Function `replace` search exactly element `<>:"/\|?*`, not every char separatelly. And it needs `title = title.replace(...)`, not `title[title.replace(...)]`

Comment: maybe first run without `try/except` to see where you have mistake, and what is FULL error message - because you may have mistake in other places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two mistakes in your code

- `replace` searchs exactly string `'<>:"/\|?*'` and you should replace every char separatelly `.replace('<',' ').replace('>',' ').replace(':',' ')` (or run it in `for`-loop)
- you have to assign `title = title.replace()`, not `title[title.replace(...)`

```
banned_char = '<>:"/\|?*'

for character in banned_char:
    title = title.replace(character,' ')

# --- after loop ---

titles[number-1] = title
```